# How do I add comments to my post dynamically with ajax?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, laravel

I'm trying to add comments to an existing post through an ajax request that updates the comments dynamically. Each post is loaded with an attribute of 'data-post-id' which holds it's id from the Post eloquent model. The data-post-id works just fine as I can see that it holds the post's id when I inspect the html element through chrome tools, however, I'm not sure how to select the post that holds the specific id and add a new comment div to it.

```
<div posts>
   <div post data-post-id="">
        <div comments>
            <div comment>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>


  $(document).on("submit","#addComments", function (e){
        e.preventDefault();

        let comment = $("input[name=comment]").val();
        let _token   = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
        let postID = $(this).attr('data-post-id');

        $.ajax({
            url:"/comments/" + postID,
            method:"POST",
            data:{
                comment:comment,
                _token:_token,
                postID:postID,
            },
            success:function(response){
                addNewComment(response,postID);
                $('#addComments')[0].reset();
                // console.log(response)
            }
        });

    });
function addNewComment(response,postID){
        var $comment = $commentTemplate.clone();
        $comment.find('[data-source="commentBody"]').html(response.comment.body);
        $comment.find('[data-source="commentCreatedTime"]').html(moment().startOf('second').fromNow());
        $('[posts]').find('[post][data-post-id="'+postID+'"]').closest('[comments]').append($comment.html());
       
    }
```

The comment are submitted to this url :

```
Route::post('/comments/{postID}',[CommentController::class,'store'])->name('addComment');
```

The form that submits comments also has the data-post-id attribute and it's contents are filled with every post.

```
<form id="addComments" class="mb-2" data-post-id="">
      @csrf
      <div class="comment-input">
          <input type="text" 
           name="comment" class="form-control" 
           placeholder="Write a new comment">
       </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: You have mutliple such forms ?

Comment: I've another form in the same page for submitting posts. Why ?

Comment: ids are same for that form ? Did you try to print postID has?

Comment: Each form has a unique ID. Yes. I get the correct postID when I inspect my html or when I log it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem comes from `.closest('[comments]')`. [closest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) returns the closest **parent** which matches the selector passed as parameter.

In your case `[comments]` is a child of `[post]` so use that instead

```js
$('[posts]').find(`[post][data-post-id="${postID}"] > [comments]`).append($comment.html());
```

Comment: Thank you, but it's still not adding the comments dynamically :( .

Comment: There are a few thing you can check. Do you have an error ? Does `$('[posts]').find(`[post][data-post-id="${postID}"] > [comments]`)` targets the right element ? Is `$comment` as expected

Comment: I get no console errors. I tried adding the data-post-id attribute to each comment to make sure it's coming in, but it doesn't seem like it's coming in.
'''$comment.find('[data-post-id]').attr('data-post-id',postID);'''